# Flow type error on redux connected component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

I'm using Flow with React and Redux. It was working perfectly well since I wrote my last component:

```
const PluginList = (props: { plugins: Plugin[] }) => {
  const { plugins } = props

  return (
    <div>
      <List selectable>
        {plugins.map(plugin => (
          <PluginListItem plugin={plugin} key={plugin.elementName} />
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The PluginListItem is a redux connected component :

```
class PluginListItem extends React.Component {
  props: { plugin: Plugin, addPlugin: Plugin => void }

  onClick = () => this.props.addPlugin(this.props.plugin)

  render() {
    const { name } = this.props.plugin
    return <ListItem onClick={this.onClick}/>
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addPlugin,
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PluginListItem)
```

My problem is that I get a strange type error complaining for missing props when I use `PluginListItem` in `PluginList` :

```
src/plugins/PluginList/PluginListItem/PluginListItem.jsx:8
  8:   props: { plugin: Plugin, addPlugin: Plugin => void }
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `addPlugin`. Property not found in
 25:           <PluginListItem plugin={plugin} key={plugin.elementName} />
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ props of React element `PluginListItem`. See: src/plugins/PluginList/PluginList.jsx:25
```

And strange thing is that it's perfectly working on other redux connected components...

Comment: I saw an issue where a type error in the implementation led to flow catching an issue further up where it was attempted to be used in redux props. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54644817/missleading-flow-type-error-in-react-props/54644818#54644818

Comment: Yes it was probably the cause of the error. And this is why I don't use flow anymore. The error reports are far from helpful and it take more time to decrypt the error message it self than debugging your program...