# Missleading flow type error in react props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flowtype

Having changed the implementation of a function added to the `DispatchProps` of a component using react-redux I got the following error:

```
yarn run v1.13.0
$ flow

Cannot call this.props.<prop> because:
 • Either property <prop> is missing in ExternalProps [1].
 • Or property <prop> is missing in ConnectProps [2].
```

However, the prop was part of the `DispatchProps`; which is intersected with the mentioned props: `type Props = ExternalProps & ConnectProps & DispatchProps`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was apparently a type-error in the implementation of the function. This seems to lead to flow not adding the function to the props and then complaining in this way - refactoring the function to use types at a more granular level had flow reporting the issue correctly.